# Do Multiplayer Teams Share Social Polices and Wonder Bonuses?

Tags: civilization-5

Although this may be a simple yes/no question if you can elaborate on the wonder bonuses it would be most appreciated. Just to clarify "share social polices" means if I unlock "Honor" does my friend unlock it as well or maybe is it only the individual policies that are shared like "discipline" (+10% Combat strength when adjacent a friendly unit).

Comment: Social policies are NOT shared. I know that for a fact. But I can't say anything about the wonders.

Comment: I believe Wonders are shared (I know they were in previous games) but I don't have a reference for that right now.

Answer (score 2):

No the social policies are not shared if on a team

Answer (score 2):

Both are not shared.  However, it is still better for your team to get it than your opponents.

Religion is also (unfortunately) not shared.  Unless one of you chooses to not create one, but at which point you lose out on many benefits.